# Force MySQL to write to a new binlog

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysqlbinlog

Is it possible to force mysql to start writing future events to a new binlog file?
In the docs it is mentioned that the final event is a log-rotation event which mentions the name of the next log [filename](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-log-structure-and-contents.html) Can we force a log-rotation event? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLUSH [BINARY] LOGS` causes a new binlog file to be started.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html

> **FLUSH BINARY LOGS**
>
> Closes and reopens any binary log file to which the server is writing.
> If binary logging is enabled, the sequence number of the binary log
> file is incremented by one relative to the previous file.
>
> This operation has no effect on tables used for the binary and relay
> logs (as controlled by the master_info_repository and
> relay_log_info_repository system variables).